# Como calcular intervalos de tempo no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha que me informa onde um caminhão estava em um determinado horario:

```
DATA/HORA      COD. REVENDA
24/1/17 0:50       1
24/1/17 0:51       1
24/1/17 0:53       1
24/1/17 0:54       1
24/1/17 0:56       1
24/1/17 0:57       1
24/1/17 0:59       2
24/1/17 1:00       2
24/1/17 1:04       2
24/1/17 1:07       2
24/1/17 3:00       1
24/1/17 3:00       1
24/1/17 3:15       1
24/1/17 3:25       1
```

O codigo 1 quer dizer que ele estava em transito e os demais são codigos de fabricas. Preciso calcular o tempo em que ele ficou em rota e o tempo que ele ficou nas fabricas mas não faço ideia de como fazer. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar 2 colunas auxiliares para facilitar o entendimento do problema.

Em uma das colunas, você vai verificar se o `COD.REVENDA` da linha em questão é igual a 1, e se o `COD.REVENDA` da linha acima é igual a 1 também, em caso afirmativo, calcule a diferença dos tempos marcados. E na outra coluna, fará o mesmo para o `COD.REVENDA = 2`.

- Célula C2: `=SE(E(B2=1;B1=1);A2-A1;"")`
- Célula D2: `=SE(E(B2=2;B1=2);A2-A1;"")`

Copie e arraste essa fórmula de modo que nas células `C10` e `D10`, as fórmulas sejam as seguintes:

- Célula C10: `=SE(E(B10=1;B9=1);A10-A9;"")`
- Célula D10: `=SE(E(B10=2;B9=2);A10-A9;"")`

E nas células `G1` e `G2`, pode colar as seguintes fórmulas para ter o total do tempo gasto em cada uma das atividades:

- G1: `=SOMA(C:C)`
- G2: `=SOMA(D:D)`

**Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, isso é fácil, basta entender como funciona.
Vou passar um link que contém exemplos muito simples para você entender as condições no Excel e adaptar ao seu caso.

Lembre-se que para obter a quantidade de tempo (horas) gasto entre dois intervalos, você pode usar algo como:

```
DATA/HORA    COD.REVENDA    TEMPO GASTO
0:50         1              =(A1 - HORARIO_INICIAL)
0:51         1              =(A2 - A1)
0:59         2              =(A3 - A2)
```

Abaixo um exemplo de uso das condições no Excel.

Tente implementar no seu caso, caso não consiga ajudaremos!

- [Trabalhar com Data/Hora no Excel](http://www.feranoexcel.com/2012/05/fazendo-calculos-operacoes-horas)
- [Somar dados com base em uma ou mais condições](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Somar-valores-com-base-em-v%C3%A1rias-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e)